# "Have g++ follow the C++14 ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++14] " not seeing in codeblock?

Tags: c++

I am new to coding and programming so please answer my question. Before i had **"Have g++ follow the C++14 ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++14]"** in my codeblock IDE. But last day i did a default reset in complier settings. After the reset **"Have g++ follow the C++14 ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++14]"** is not visible in the complier flags options. I tried re-installation of codeblock but it didnt work. how to reset codeblock to get the option back. Also what is the difference between ...std c++14 and ..std c++11.

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What version of g++ are you using?

Comment: What is a "default reset in complier settings"?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between c++11 and c++14 is minor.
Each one is a standard, which defines what c++ is. C++14 mostly extends C++11 with features, that didnt make it in time to c++11.
Its rather an extension to c++11, then a big jump in version like c++03 to c++11.

Using c++14 in Codeblocks must be done with the Compilerflags.
These must enable --std=c++14 -> The settings is not related to Codeblocks, but to the compiler that codeblocks uses.